# Custom complex form validation on select inputs

Tags: jquery, html

I have a form that contains 10 select menus that makes the user arrange a league of legends match between 2 teams .
5 select menus for team A and 5 select menus for team B .
Each select contains 4 groups of 5 players like following :

```
<select name="teamA_first" id="teamA_first" class="team_A">
    <option value="0">select</option>
    <optgroup label="group1"></optgroup>
        <option data-guild="1" value="1">player 1</option>
        <option data-guild="1" value="2">player 2</option>
        <option data-guild="1" value="3">player 3</option>
        <option data-guild="1" value="4">player 4</option>
        <option data-guild="1" value="5">player 5</option>
    <optgroup label="group2"></optgroup>
        <option data-guild="2" value="6">player 6</option>
        <option data-guild="2" value="7">player 7</option>
        <option data-guild="2" value="8">player 8</option>
        <option data-guild="2" value="9">player 9</option>
        <option data-guild="2" value="10">player 10</option>
    <optgroup label="group3"></optgroup>
        <option data-guild="3" value="11">player 11</option>
        <option data-guild="3" value="12">player 12</option>
        <option data-guild="3" value="13">player 13</option>
        <option data-guild="3" value="14">player 14</option>
        <option data-guild="3" value="15">player 15</option>
    <optgroup label="group4"></optgroup>
        <option data-guild="4" value="16">player 16</option>
        <option data-guild="4" value="17">player 17</option>
        <option data-guild="4" value="18">player 18</option>
        <option data-guild="4" value="19">player 19</option>
        <option data-guild="4" value="20">player 20</option>        
</select>
```

I want to validate the form like following :

Each Team must contain at least one player from each group .

For example Team A must contain at least one player from group1 , one from group2 ,one from group3 and one from group4 .

Same for Team B .

I made a function that solved this but I think it could be more optimized :

```
$( "#addMatchForm" ).submit(function( event ) {
        var $inputs_a = $('#addMatchForm :input.team_A');
        var $inputs_b = $('#addMatchForm :input.team_B');

        var values_a = [];
        var values_b = [];
        $inputs_a.each(function(index, value) {
            values_a[index] = $(this).find(':selected').data('guild');
        });
        $inputs_b.each(function(index, value) {
            values_b[index] = $(this).find(':selected').data('guild');
        });

        var g1 = 1;
        var g2 = 2;
        var g3 = 3;
        var g4 = 4;
        //count guilds occurences on team A selects
        var a_occ1 = $.grep(values_a, function (elem , i) {
            return elem == g1;
        }).length;
        var a_occ2 = $.grep(values_a, function (elem , i) {
            return elem == g2;
        }).length;
        var a_occ3 = $.grep(values_a, function (elem , i) {
            return elem == g3;
        }).length;
        var a_occ4 = $.grep(values_a, function (elem , i) {
            return elem == g4;
        }).length;

        //count guilds occurences on team B selects
        var b_occ1 = $.grep(values_b, function (elem , i) {
            return elem == g1;
        }).length;
        var b_occ2 = $.grep(values_b, function (elem , i) {
            return elem == g2;
        }).length;
        var b_occ3 = $.grep(values_b, function (elem , i) {
            return elem == g3;
        }).length;
        var b_occ4 = $.grep(values_b, function (elem , i) {
            return elem == g4;
        }).length;

        var error = false ;
        if(a_occ1 < 1){
            error = true ;
            alert('No players from team 沖縄のトラ selected on Team A! You must at least choose one player from each team .');
        }
        if(a_occ2 < 1){
            error = true ;
            alert('No players from team Ozone Rampage selected on Team A! You must at least choose one player from each team .');
        }
        if(a_occ3 < 1){
            error = true ;
            alert('No players from team Rascal Jester selected on Team A! You must at least choose one player from each team .');
        }
        if(a_occ4 < 1){
            error = true ;
            alert('No players from team DetnatioN FM selected on Team A! You must at least choose one player from each team .');
        }
        if(b_occ1 < 1){
            error = true ;
            alert('No players from team 沖縄のトラ selected on Team B! You must at least choose one player from each team .');
        }
        if(b_occ2 < 1){
            error = true ;
            alert('No players from team Ozone Rampage selected on Team B! You must at least choose one player from each team .');
        }
        if(b_occ3 < 1){
            error = true ;
            alert('No players from team Rascal Jester selected on Team B! You must at least choose one player from each team .');
        }
        if(b_occ4 < 1){
            error = true ;
            alert('No players from team DetnatioN FM selected on Team B! You must at least choose one player from each team .');
        }

        if(error){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }       

    });
```

Any ideas ?
Thank you

Comment: The community isn't really about doing your work for you, it's about helping overcome problems with what you've already tried. Show us the code you've tried so far, point out the problems you're having, and ask for help with specific issues. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I already made a function that does the work but I am looking for an optimized version .